# React.Fragment wraps rows into div instead of table

Tags: reactjs

I apologize in advance but I can't get my head around the following. According to the doc https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#usage,

...the following code :

```
class Columns extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>World</td>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

should result in :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>World</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But in my app it doesn't work, the following code wraps both td tags in a div component:

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (      
<Columns/>    
    );
  }
}

export default App;

class Columns extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>World</td>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?? These are the dependencies I'm using in my package.json file :

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are you rendering the `App` component? Are you sure the `div` you are seeing isn't just the container root?

Comment: @Tholle yes it's the container root. I mistook the whole Fragment concept. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In example](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#motivation) author added table to component

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          <Columns />
        </tr>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

And you returns only Columns without table and tr

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (      
      <Columns/>    
    );
  }
}
```

You should add table/tr by yourself and it will work

Answer (score 0):

`React.Fragment` allows you to return multiple elements without needing to wrap them. Your App component is simply rendering:

`<td>Hello</td>
<td>World</td>`

Depending on where you're rendering your app component, you may end up with invalid DOM nesting (ie. you should have a `<table/>` and `<tr/>` in your example). The browser does it's best with our muck ups and tries to correct things, which may be why you have extra divs.